Error in graphing the polar equation $r=-1+\cos(\theta)$. I get a different answer than the book for cos(30degrees). Am I wrong?
I have included a picture of the table that is shown in the answer key. Most of the answers coincide with what I get by using various calculators, but some don't and I don't know if I am making some sort of mistake rounding (I'm rounding to the nearest 1/10th, as is the book, apparently).
I don't know if there is a typo in the book or what. These are all in degrees from 0 degrees to 360 degrees.
I'll give you an example of my problem. If I enter 30 degrees for theta, I get -.133 and so on, which I round to -.1 but the book says it is .7 as you can see in the table.
It goes on for several apparent errors, though when it gets to quadrantal angles, the book seems to have the correct answer and coincides with what I get.
I know it's not terribly important, but the mistakes I make help me to learn more, so any help would be appreciated.

$ cos 30^\circ = \frac{\sqrt 3}{2} \approx 0.866, $   subtract $1$   and you get $\approx -0.134$

My guess is that you are using your calculator(s) incorrectly. As a simple check, the cosine of 30 deg is definitely less than 1, so when you subtract 1 from it you should have a negative number.

Note that Will's calculation shows that the book's answer is also wrong.

It's wrong. Here is why. You can directly put the value and check. It's wrong for $90°$ part as well. For a more general approach:-
$f(x)=-1+\cosθ$  has maximum value of $0$ at $θ=0°$ and minimum value of $-1$ at $θ=90°$ $\forall x \in [0°,90°]$
It's a decreasing function, which can be proved by its derivative
$$f'(x)=-\sin(x), x \in [0°,90°]$$
In the given interval, value of $(-\sin x)$ is always negative, so $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$ if $x_1<x_2$.
And thus the value given in the table is wrong.

I haven't started using some of the notation you listed, but from what I do understand, I think you are correct. The book has typos.

I'm so sorry. Please tell me what you didn't understand.

Well, I'm learning trig now and the book has different notation. Also, I haven't started what I assume would be calculus for learning about the derivative. I'll learn it eventually, but right now, I'm essentially doing pre-cal. But, I understand how you have the interval from 0 degrees to 90 degrees as an example. And I understand that cos 90 degrees would be 0, so adding negative 1 to it, would result in -1, though the book says 0. Basically, I understand that the book is wrong, though I don't know how derivatives work...yet. Thanks for your reply. It makes me want to learn more math!

I should say by different notation, the book doesn't use the big epsilon looking symbol for sets. And the book hasn't gotten around to the upside down A. So, that is what I mean by different notation. They just give the interval without the big E symbol. I actually looked up the symbol online and I understand it to mean an element of a certain set. I'm learning. I'll get there. Thanks a lot for your help.

Okay, I'm trying to explain it. You have learnt straight lines, did you? Did you ever notice the slope there. You would always see, it the slope of a line is (+)ve, the line rises upwards as we move towards (+)ve x direction, making each corresponding y value increase. But if the slope is (-)ve, the line points downwards as we move towards (+)ve x direction. This means each y value corresponding with x decreases.  An advanced form of this concept is used in derivatives, which are like slopes,but at a certain point.

That inverted A $\forall$ is known to describe "for all". It's like " for all x in the following interval". Alright?

I hope you weren't bothered by my comment. I meant it as praise. I really did appreciate it. I understand 90% of what you are saying. I just haven't learned derivatives yet. And yes, now I know what the inverted A means, which I appreciate.

@DavidA. No no I wasn't bothered at all. You're such an eager student, I am happy that I could explain better. I wish a great day to you
